# Defining Equivalence Relations on a Set

Tags: relations

Given the sets, $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{12,1,2\pi\}$, define (by listing the ordered pairs):

$a$) A relation from $A$ to $B$ that is not a function.

$b$) A relation from $A$ to $B$ that is a function.

I was thinking for $b$ that since $A\times B$ is $A$ going to $B$, then I need to write something like:

```
x y
0 1  
12 1
```

which will give $(0*1) -(12*1)= -12$. But I'm not exactly sure that this is right with the right notation.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Write down the *definition* of a relation that **is** a function. What must be true for a relation **not** to be a function?

Answer (score 0):

A relation is a subset of the Cartesian product of the sets.  $R\subseteq A{\times} B$.  That is, it is a set of ordered pairs whose members are one of the first set, and one of the second (in that order).

$$R = \{(x,y)\in A{\times}B \mid \textsf{some definition}\}$$

$$A{\times}B = \{(1,12), (1, 1), (1, 2\pi), (0, 12), (0, 1), (0, 2\pi)\}$$

So what you are being asked to do is provide *examples* of such a subset that: (a) is not a function, and (b) is so a function.

This is a test of your knowledge of what is a function, and your practical skills in applying that knowledge.

So, now, back to you:   What is a function?